# Updating classes used in multiple projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a few classes that are abstracted in a way that I can use them in multiple projects.  I'm always working on these classes, optimizing, adding, etc.  So when I optimize something in one of these classes, I then need to copy that new version into every project I remember using it.  This isn't a very good way of doing it, but is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: All answers mention *Class Library* projects, which are usually the way to go, though there can be reasons to reference files instead of compiled libraries; please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instead of manually copying the updated classes to every project that uses them, create a *Class Library* project and reference the compiled file in every project that uses the classes.** Organizing your classes like that will help you to follow the DRY ("Don't repeat yourself") principle.

---

If you **need** to reference files instead of compiled libraries, however, you can reference a file as a link so that multiple projects refer to the same file without copying it to each solution folder. To do that, right-click on your project, choose *Add existing item...*, browse to the `.cs` file, and choose *Add as Link* from the combobox in the right lower corner.

Answer (score 5):

Put these base classes in a single project and share this project between your different solutions as an referenced class library. This way you will not have to copy / paste anything between projects or solutions and everything should always be up to date.

You could even set-up a local [NuGet feed](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds) so you can use NuGet to retrieve this shared project as a reference in a well structured and managed way.

Comment: Agree shearing files between projects is not always the best way of doing things. Try to extract common staff into one or several libraries. Unless you have a real reason of not doing this. Let us know if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

How about if you extract the classes into a separate project, and add a reference to this project in every project you are using?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to copy paste file throughout the application. To avoid these repetitions you can either:

1. make a link, if the amount of file is really small . In the *Solution browser* of Visual Studio, right click, **Add Existing file**, chose your file and in the split button, choose **Add as a link**
2. create a separate project and reference this project wherever is is necessary if the amount of files **not** tiny.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base-lib and build it to a "shared" location. Add a reference to it in you project. It will keep the other projects smaller and will be faster to build.